# Sort function, helpers.c, only listing a few numbers

Tags: c, sorting

My sort function only seems to list 3 numbers out of a thousand repeatedly. Not sure why. Any ideas?

My sort array begins here. I created a for loop that iterates through n numbers. Then I compare the values and create a swap algorithm. I assume my swap algorithm is flawed.

```
/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{        
    //TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] < values[i + 1])
        {         
          int holder = values[i];
          values[i] = holder;
          values[i + 1] = values[i];
          values[i] = holder;
          printf("%i\n", values[i]);                
        }       
    }       
    return;        
}
```

Comment: Don't you do a `values[i] = holder;`to many? If you learn to use a debugger and how to step through code line by line, problems like this are really easy to find. And it might be a good idea to learn how to use the debugger anyway, because your `sort` function will not fully sort the array.

Comment: And by the way, if you have problem with sorting, why do you show us the unrelated `search` function? You might want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic error in the following lines:

```
    int holder = values[i];
    values[i] = holder;
    values[i + 1] = values[i];
    values[i] = holder;
```

I assume you want to swap the value of `values[i]` and `values[i+1]`.

You are not extracting the value of `values[i+1]` anywhere in that code to assign it to `values[i]`.

You need to use:

```
    int holder = values[i];
    values[i] = values[i + 1];
    values[i + 1] = holder;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still seem to be getting a list of unsorted numbers though.

Comment: That's because your sorting algorithm is not complete. You can look for various sorting algorithms in Wikipedia and implement the simplest sorting algorithm -- [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: If you have large arrays to sort, bubble-sort is one of the *least* efficient sorting algorithms. Grab a copy of the *quicksort* algorithm which can be *orders of magnitude* faster on larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not implementing bubble sort correctly. Do it like follows-

```
/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{        
    //TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
        if (values[j+1] < values[j])
        {         
          int holder = values[j];
          values[j] = values[j + 1] 
          values[j + 1] = holder;

          printf("%i\n", values[j]);                
        }   
        }     
    }       
    return;        
}
```

In your algorithm you were traversing the array only once(as there was just one for loop) whereas for sorting to work properly,you need to have two nested loops.